# How to send authentication email with sendgrid

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid

[image: This image describes the error I get]

I have these lines of code, but having difficulty sending mail using SendGrid. I need a working guide to what can be done.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY)

const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(name, email, password)
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const firstError = errors.array().map(error => error.msg)[0];
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: firstError
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({
      email
    }).exec((err, user) => {
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: 'Email is taken'
        });
      }
    });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        name,
        email,
        password
      },
      process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
      {
        expiresIn: '5m'
      }
    );

    const emailData = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      to: email,
      subject: 'Account activation link',
      html: `
                <h1>Please use the following to activate your account</h1>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/users/activate/${token}</p>
                <hr />
                <p>This email may containe sensetive information</p>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
            `
    };

sgMail.send(emailData)
                .then(sent => {
                  return res.json({
                    message: `Email has been sent to ${email}`
                  });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                   console.log(err)
                  return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    errors: errorHandler(err)
                  });
                });
```

The above code is the code I have, but I get the error described in the image which is the `catch` to the `.then` of the `sgMail.send`. I get a forbidden error in the console. I don't know where that is really coming from

Comment: Can you log out what the error is in the `catch` before you return the response and let me know what that says?

Comment: ResponseError: Forbidden
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\My projects\greenlifeapp\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:146:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  code: 403,}

Comment: “Forbidden” sounds like you’ve got your credentials wrong. Double check you’ve got them set correctly and that the API key has the correct permissions. Also, where are you setting the API key in your code?

Comment: Yes! I forgot to create a sender identity, it works now